# saving data in a text file from arduino

Tags: arduino

i have a arduino temperature measurement device which will use LM35 sensors to measure temperature.Electrical side was not my area. I am working with a c program which will get the average two different data from two different sensors and write it to a file. This is the first time i am writing a c program for a micro controller. I am getting this error:

> "fopen' was not declared in this scope

why i am getting this error? how to solve this?

```
int sensor1 = A0;
int sensor2 = A1;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(sensor1,INPUT);
  pinMode(sensor2,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  analogReference(INTERNAL1V1);
}

void loop()
{
int temp1 = analogRead(sensor1);
int temp2 = analogRead(sensor2);
double t1 = ((1.100000001/1024)*temp1)/.01;
double t2 = ((1.100000001/1024)*temp2)/.01;
double tempavg=(t1+t2)/2;
FILE *fp;
if(fp=fopen('myfile.txt','w')){
   fprintf(fp,"%d",tempavg);
   fclose(fp);
}
Serial.print(temp1);
Serial.print("     ");
Serial.println(t1,4);
Serial.print(temp2);
Serial.print("     ");
Serial.println(t2,4);
Serial.println("----------------");
delay(2000);

}
```

Comment: Please always start by reading [the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) for standard C functions that you don't understand.

Comment: `fopen('myfile.txt','w')` --> `fopen("myfile.txt","w")`

Comment: While these are great suggestions, Arduino does not have any conventional file storage or filesystem. There are different libraries for working with SD card, but I believe it is not the case here.

Comment: i never worked with an arduino board before..if there is a way to keep record of values in a file ..let me know.

Comment: If you want to save on a PC you need to write a native application (Windows, Linux, etc) to monitor serial input from the Arduino and save to disk.

Comment: Send them to the computer via Serial, as you do, and record them there.

Comment: you mean with php?if so how can i connect php with arduino?

Comment: Any language. See @JohnnyMopp's comment update..

Comment: You have two easy options for storing data in Arduino. Arduino chip has an EEPROM memory that could store some byte(size depends of version) or you could add and SDcard module to your Arduino and use it for storing. In the other hand you could send via serial the data to a computer and read/store/use it, in this case you could use your favorite language.

Answer (score -1):

you need to include the library that has that function. Sometimes it's also good to just copy paste the error message to google and read whatever comes to you in the beginning.As time goes by, your eyes will get trained on how to sort the useful from useless information to your particular problem. 
[C++ program compilation fails in Ubuntu, but works in MacOSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953610/c-program-compilation-fails-in-ubuntu-but-works-in-macosx)

Comment: What is the included link meant to do?  It's not clear whether it's meant to answer the poster's question directly, or to illustrate the (benefits of the) pattern of looking up error messages.